# Is the field goal good?

Tags: american-football, nfl, field-goal

During a field goal, if the ball hits the ground and bounces through the uprights and above the crossbar, is it still good despite hitting the ground first?

Answer (score 6):

No. Rule 11 Section 4 Article 1 states:

> Article 1 Successful Field Goal. A field goal is scored when all of
> the following conditions are met:
>
> (b) After the ball is kicked, it must not touch the ground or any
> player of the offensive team before it passes through the goal.

http://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/image/rulebook/pdfs/14_2013_Scoring.pdf